# jQuery to select next table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two rows of a table here. When I click the checkbox in the first table row, I'm trying to target the ID of the span in the next table row. I have an alert in my code just to show me that I was successful.

What I have isn't working. I can't figure out a way to select data in the next table row when the checkbox in the first row is clicked.

```
<table>
<tr id="row-a">
<td>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>
        some text
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <span id="target">
        some text
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var myCheck = $("tr#row-a td input");

   myCheck.change(function(){
   var spanID = $("tr#row-a').next('tr').find('span').attr('id');
   alert(spanID);
   });
});
```

Comment: And the table I'm working with doesn't have unique identifiers on the TRs other than the one row that I have the checkbox in.

Comment: You are looking for `$(this).closest('tr')` instead of `$("tr#row-a')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myCheck = $("tr#row-a td input");
myCheck.change(function(){
    var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span').attr('id');
    alert(spanID);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MUWAP/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myCheck = $("tr#row-a td input");

   myCheck.change(function(){
   var spanID = myCheck.parents("tr").next().find('span').attr('id');
   alert(spanID);
   });
});
```

The change was in this line:

```
   var spanID = myCheck.parents("tr").next().find('span').attr('id');
```

Which does the following:

- Finds the checkbox's `tr` parent
- Gets the next sibling node (next `tr`)
- Finds the `span`
- Gets its id